# Wrapper for method with a block

Tags: ruby

I want to use the combination method with a custom class.

If my class looks like this...

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @data = []
  end
  def to_a
    @data
  end
end
```

I could call this...

```
myobj = MyClass.new
myobj.to_a.combination(2) {|a,b| puts "#{a} #{b}" }
```

But I'd much rather have this...

```
myobj.combination {|a,b| puts "#{a} #{b}" }
```

I've tried to write a class method to wrap the combination method, passing the block. But it's not working.

```
def combination(&block)
  @data.to_a.combination(2) block.call
end
```

Also, does anyone know why combination is in the Array class and not Enumerable? I'd have thought it would have been more useful there.

Comment: if your class ressembles an array so much, why not inherit from Array?

Comment: "why combination is in the Array class and not Enumerable?" To build combinations of elements you need all the elements beforehand, that's why it makes sense to have it in Array, so the method is in this class. Of course it could be in Enumerable instead and do that array conversion internally, but I guess devs thought that would be more clear.

Comment: @tokland I thought about that, but I didn't want all the Array methods. Also, I wanted to learn how to solve this problem!

Comment: of course! Chowlett answer is the one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The block is a special type of parameter to Array#combination (much like you've got it in your own definition). The correct invocation is:

```
def combination(&block)
  @data.to_a.combination(2, &block)
end
```

Comment: minor detail: from the question it would appear that @data is already an array, so no need of to_a here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def combination(&block)
  @data.to_a.combination(2) { block }
end
```

Comment: this won't work, you meant `block.call`? sending the block directly to `combination` is less verbose anyway.